# Stitch two images in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I want to make panoram images.
first I want to stitch two images together. Using Sift and Ransac I can find the Homography and by using the function

`warpPerspective(projectedImg[5], stitchedImage, H, Point(projectedImg[5].cols + projectedImg[4].cols, Rows));`
I receive the transformed image of second image.

I have two questions:

1 - in this function where is the starting point for peforming the transform?

2 - sometimge using this function the corners of the image go out of boundry of `stitchedImage` how can I make a bigger image to prevent this problem?

Comment: 2. Make projectedImg[5].cols + projectedImg[4].cols or Rows a bigger value

Comment: When I make Rows bigger, the bottom right corner does not go out of border but top right corner goes out of border. in other words, increasing Rows just increase from bottom.

Comment: You can shift the whole result by multiplying a 3x3 translation to your homography from left.